# Is there any jQuery plugin that couples 2 elements such that if one changes, the other does too?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select boxes such that changing options in one has to be followed by a change in the options of the other. Is there a plugin that couples the two in order to make it easy to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to weigh down the site loading an unnecessary plugin, use this:

```
$(".select1").change(function () { 
    $(".select2").val($(".select1").val());
});
```

For this example you only need jQuery, but if you don't want to use it it can be easily transformed to make it using native DOM functions.